# zsh: How to declare associative array programmatically?

Tags: zsh

To declare associative array programmatically, I tried this:

```
foo=bar
typeset -A "${foo}"=(
  [key1]="hello world"
  [key2]=baz
)
```

Whatever I try, I'm getting:

> zsh: unknown sort specifier

How to declare an associative array using a variable to set its name ?

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the best way, but you can use indirect parameter expansion  *after* declaring the name to be an associative array.

```
foo=bar
typeset -A "${(p)foo}"
typeset "${(p)foo}[hello]=world"
```

You can also use `set -A`

```
foo=bar
set -A $foo hello world
```